# iCarousel class doesn't work with ARC on xcode 4.2 & mac os 10.6

Tags: icarousel

I'd like to include the iCarousel class and use it to make a gallery, 
but the problem is that it doesn't work, if i include it.
I tried to use it with ARC and without - no effect.
Xcode finds about 20 errors in iCarousel.m :
for all messages like [self stopAnimation], [self layOutItemViews], [self ....] ..
it's written "ARC receiver type 'iCarousel' for instance message doesn't declare a method with selector..

i work on xcode 4.2 and Mac OS X 10.6.8

I download this tutorial  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-creating-an-awesome-carousel/ 
and it works, but there's no iCarousel effect - just a scroll with the list of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCarousel doesn't support Xcode 4.2 or Snow Leopard any more. The minimum supported version is 4.3 on Lion.

If you want to run it on 4.2 (bearing in mind that Apple no longer accept apps to the app store that are built with 4.2) you can download an older version from this page:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/tags

I believe version 1.6.1 and earlier worked on 4.2, but if you still get errors with it, just keep downloading an earlier version until you find one that works.

EDIT: To be clear, apps built using iCarousel *do* still support Snow Leopard, but you cannot *develop* using Snow Leopard.

Comment: Thank you, Nick, for the fast answer!

Comment: version 1.6.1 is ok) tnx again